# Extract list of Sellers with TTM > 100k for the last 3 months in SQL (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Quick question:
I want to extract a list of sellers with TTM sales > 100k for the last 3 months. I need a snapshot of the data for the last 3-4 months:

1. Sellers which have TTM sales > 100k in January
2. Sellers which have TTM sales > 100k in Febr
3. Sellers which have TTM sales > 100k in March
   I want to create it in a **dynamic way** on which if I want to extract the data for 6 months, only need to change > Jan to > Oct and store the data in a table
   Eg. Jan - 100 sellers, Febr. 200 sellers, March - 75 Sellers

Table used:

1. Seller list (id, marketplace)

[image]

2. Sales (id, marketplace, sale_day, sale_amount)

[image]

Output 1 - TTM:

[image]

Output 2 - TTM (only sellers > 100k):

[image]

This last output has to be dynamic. I want to get the last 3 months data based on a "RUN_DATE". per eligible seller

TTM = Trailing Twelve Months (sales per seller on the last 12 months)
eg. Sales in Jan (Jan 2020 - Dec 2020)
Sales in Febr (Febr 2020 - Jan 2021)
Thise has to be filterer by 100k.
My actual logic is to take a snapshot of them per month Jan , Febr, March and union.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) in a tabular form. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name did it. thx.

Comment: What is "TTM sales"?  This is not a column in the data.  What is "run date per eligible user"?

Comment: TTM sales - Trailing twelve months (sum of sales on the last 12 months per seller)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want aggregation:

```
select id, date_trunc('month', sale_date) as yyyymm,
       sum(sale_amount) as total_sales
from sales
group by yyyymm, id;
```

Then for the last 3 months and filtering, you would do:

```
select id, date_trunc('month', sale_date) as yyyymm,
       sum(sale_amount) as total_sales
from sales s
where s.sale_date >= date_trunc('month', now()) - interval '3' month
group by yyyymm, id
having sum(sale_amount) > 100000;
```

Comment: thanks. This is the easiest way but does not work in my case. Why? Because in Jan I need to see TTM sales (Jan 2020 - Dec 2020) and filter on 100k. In Febr. I need to see TTM sales (Febr. 2020 - Jan 2021) and filter on 100k...and so on...